# What's the fastest file system setup for transferring from NVME to HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, raid

I'm trying to figure out the proper system layout for transferring data from fast storage to slow storage with minimal bottlenecks. I have a fast array of RAID 0 NVME drives used for daily tasks. At set intervals I'll transfer data no longer used to HDDs for long term storage. I'd like to minimize the time the NVME drives spend transferring data.

Which file systems should be used on the NVME drive? I'm guessing ext4 would be a good choice. Which on the HDDs? Would ZFS provide any speed benefits?

Comment: Maybe you are asking the wrong questions.  Using compression (like gzip) might be beneficial if the system is io constrained and the data is compressible. 3.5" Drives with faster rpm are likely to provide the fastest sustained transfer, provided they are not fragmented.  Im not sure that things like filesystem will make a significant impact. If your hdds are internal you might benefit from something like zfs if you assign an ssd as a cache for them, but that wont be very practical for removable HDDs, and IMHO ZFS - while cool - is not really designed for removable archive storage.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I might run into problems with data loss from removing the drives. Maybe, if I put everything together at once. But, that sounds like an untested use case. I do think compressing all the data on one nvme, while doing work on another would be ideal.

Comment: Why not just read data off ssd, compress in memory and output to hdd? ( This is fairly straight forward under unix/linux etc - and as you mentioned zfs I assume you are using something like that) - "tar -czf" was designed for precisely this use case, but there are plenty other ways as well.

Comment: Hmm, I bet I could store it to memory. I might not be able to compress it since it's a crypto currency block. This is going to definitely be a month of benchmarking different storage layouts.